# Diff/merge for CAD in 2022?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, electrical-engineering, cad, solidworks, project-management

I'm fairly new as an ME, recently graduated so I'm used to working solo. Wondering how teams collaborate and do version control when working on an assembly together.

In software, git's diff/merge features are insanely helpful - for CAD I know of SVN, GitHub's STL diff tool, GrabCAD Workbench, Autodesk Vault. None of these handle diff and merge well, do you guys know any tools to tackle this? Or am I thinking of this the wrong way? Would ME teams' workflows even benefit from a tool like this?